# Process ID function getting error "ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES"

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to get the ID from a process using the function below, however GetLastError keeps returning ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES so it never gets the chance to iterate through all the processes. Im not sure whats causing this. Any ideas? Also as a test i was passing in the param as "notepad.exe"

```
int GetProcID(string ProcName){
    PROCESSENTRY32 PE32;
    HANDLE ProcSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);

    PE32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if(!Process32First(ProcSnapshot,&PE32))
        return 0;
    else
        if(PE32.szExeFile == ProcName)
            return PE32.th32ProcessID;
        else
        {
            while(GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES){
                Process32Next(ProcSnapshot,&PE32);
                    if(PE32.szExeFile == ProcName)
                        return PE32.th32ProcessID;
            }
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: A most-interesting condition in your `if()` blocks. I don't suppose you ran this in a debugger?

Comment: You're also leaking the handle returned from `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`. You might want to fix that while you're at it (or post your *real* code if this isn't it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop is wrong. You shouldn't be checking for the error value even before calling `Process32Next` function. Your function will return without doing anything if the prior call to a Windows API function (probably another `Process32Next` function) returned `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`, and the name of the first process in the snapshot happens to be something other than the name you want to search for.

Keep in mind that not all API functions set the error code to `ERROR_SUCCESS` even they have succeeded (and also don't forget to close the snapshot handle after you're done with it).

Comment: Thanks man. Using a different check method now for the while loop and it seems to be working.